# What's the proper viewing order of Hidamari Sketch series?

Tags: hidamari-sketch

There are lots of series out there called "Hidamari Sketch" -something and I'm not sure in which order to watch them. Can you help me out with that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might as well watch them in production/publishing order:

1. Hidamari Sketch
2. Hidamari Sketch (special)
3. Hidamari Sketch × 365 (TV)
4. Hidamari Sketch × 365 (special)
5. Hidamari Sketch × Hoshimittsu (TV)
6. Hidamari Sketch × Hoshimittsu (special)
7. Hidamari Sketch × SP (special)
8. Hidamari Sketch × Honeycomb (TV) (sequel)
9. Hidamari Sketch: Sae/Hiro Sotsugyō-hen (OAV)

(listing from [ANN's page](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=6811).  Everything except the last OAV is [on Hulu](http://www.hulu.com/search?q=Hidamari+Sketch) - the specials are part of the previous main season)

The problem is that *episodes* aren't completely in chronological order.  There're two groups:

- Hidamari Sketch + Hidamari Sketch × 365 (Yuno & Miyako year 1)
- × Hoshimittsu + × SP + × Honeycomb + Sae/Hiro Sotsugyō-hen (Yuno & Miyako year 2)

Episodes in the first groups are less ordered.  Episodes in the second group are more in order, but also have some episodes that chronologically take place during the first group.

Answer (score 5):

I completely agree with @Clockwork-Muse' suggestion that, if you're a first time watcher, release order is definitely the way to go.
The show was made in that order and cues in later episodes (even if set in the past) will have no effect if you haven't seen what they're referencing from a previous ep.

However, for everyone else that, like me, rocked up at this question because you're generally curious about what the actual order might be <sup>(instead of just being ushered away with *`don't you worry about that`*)</sup>, I'm writing this for you.
This is no Haruhi, but I don't doubt that it'd be cool to go chronological for a rewatch of the show, get a new perspective and watch the characters grow together.

```
╔════════════════════════════════╤═════════╦══════╤══════════╗
║             Season             │ Episode ║ Year │   Date   ║
╠════════════════════════════════╪═════════╬══════╪══════════╣
║ Hidamari Sketch x Hoshi        │    9 A  ║    0 │ 22nd Nov ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x365           │    1    ║    1 │ 10th Feb ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x365           │    7    ║    1 │  7th Apr ║
║ Hidamari Sketch                │   11    ║    1 │ 28th Apr ║
║ Hidamari Sketch                │    4    ║    1 │ 18th May ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x365           │    3    ║    1 │ 27th May ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x365           │ SP 2    ║    1 │  6th Jun ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x365           │   10    ║    1 │  8th Jun ║
║ Hidamari Sketch                │    3    ║    1 │ 17th Jun ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x365           │   12    ║    1 │  8th Jul ║
║ Hidamari Sketch                │    6    ║    1 │ 14th Jul ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x365           │    6 A  ║    1 │ 30th Jul ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x365           │    9 A  ║    1 │  5th Aug ║
║ Hidamari Sketch                │ SP 1    ║    1 │ 11th Aug ║
║ Hidamari Sketch                │    2    ║    1 │ 21st Aug ║
║ Hidamari Sketch                │ SP 3    ║    1 │ 26th Aug ║
║ Hidamari Sketch                │    9    ║    1 │  4th Sep ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Hoshi        │    8 B  ║    1 │ 26th Sep ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x365           │   11    ║    1 │ 28th Sep ║
║ Hidamari Sketch                │    7    ║    1 │ 12th Oct ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x365           │    8    ║    1 │ 13th Oct ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x365           │    4 B  ║    1 │ 31st Oct ║
║ Hidamari Sketch                │   10    ║    1 │  3rd Nov ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x365           │    6 B  ║    1 │ 11th Nov ║
║ Hidamari Sketch                │ SP 2    ║    1 │ 27th Nov ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x365           │    9 B  ║    1 │  3rd Dec ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Hoshi        │    3 B  ║    1 │ 10th Dec ║
║ Hidamari Sketch                │   12    ║    1 │ 25th Dec ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x365           │   13    ║    2 │ 10th Jan ║
║ Hidamari Sketch                │    1    ║    2 │ 11th Jan ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Hoshi        │    5 B  ║    2 │ 31th Jan ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x365           │    2    ║    2 │  6th Feb ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x365           │ SP 1    ║    2 │ 10th Feb ║
║ Hidamari Sketch                │    5    ║    2 │ 13th Feb ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Hoshi        │   11 B  ║    2 │ 16th Feb ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x365 OVA/EX    │         ║    2 │ 24th Feb ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Hoshi        │    1 A  ║    2 │ 27th Feb ║
║ Hidamari Sketch                │    8    ║    2 │ 13th Mar ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x365           │    4 A  ║    2 │ 16th Mar ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x365           │    5    ║    2 │ 25th Mar ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Hoshi        │    1 B  ║    2 │  1st Apr ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Hoshi        │    2    ║    2 │  6th Apr ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Hoshi        │    3 A  ║    2 │  8th Apr ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Hoshi        │    4    ║    2 │ 15th Apr ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Hoshi        │    5 A  ║    2 │ 20th Apr ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Hoshi        │    6    ║    2 │ 26th Apr ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Hoshi        │    7    ║    2 │  3rd May ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x SP           │    2 A  ║    2 │  9th May ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Hoshi        │    8 A  ║    2 │ 13th May ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Honey        │    1    ║    2 │  6th May ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Honey        │    2    ║    2 │ 18th May ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Hoshi        │    9 B  ║    2 │ 21st May ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x SP           │    2 B  ║    2 │ 25th May ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Hoshi        │   10    ║    2 │ 28th May ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Hoshi        │   11 A  ║    2 │  5th Jun ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x SP           │    1 A  ║    2 │ 15th Jul ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Hoshi        │   12    ║    2 │ 12th Jul ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Hoshi        │ SP 1    ║    2 │ 11th Jun ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x SP           │    1 B  ║    2 │ 28th Aug ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Honey        │    3    ║    2 │ 31st Aug ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Honey        │    4    ║    2 │ 15th Sep ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Honey        │    5 A  ║    2 │ 17th Sep ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Honey        │    6 A  ║    2 │ 25th Sep ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Honey        │    5 B  ║    2 │ 28th sep ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Honey        │    6 B  ║    2 │ 29th Sep ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Honey        │    7    ║    2 │  5th Oct ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Honey        │    8    ║    2 │ 11th Oct ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Honey        │    9    ║    2 │ 10th Nov ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Honey        │   10    ║    2 │  2nd Dec ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Honey        │   11 A  ║    2 │ 22nd Dec ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Honey        │   11 B  ║    2 │ 24th Dec ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Honey        │   12    ║    2 │ 31st Dec ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Sae and Hiro │    1    ║    3 │  1st Feb ║
║ Hidamari Sketch x Sae and Hiro │    2    ║    3 │ 28th Feb ║
╚════════════════════════════════╧═════════╩══════╧══════════╝
```

<sub>**Year** refers to the year of Yuno being at Hidamari. The first entry predates this. If **Episode** contains the *SP* prefix it means it is of the specials associated with that season, and if it has an *A* or *B* suffix it means it is only talking about the first/second half of that episode respectively!</sub>

I found [this thread](http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=1337297) where `Viteracf` has listed the order of the ep's for all four seasons! I tidied up his table [a lot] but you're gonna wanna consult his version if you want his notes on specific entries in the table (like why he put X before Y, or to see an uncovered anachronistic mistake).

<sub>`Centent` [also made a list](http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=301911) before that shows things in a slightly differing order, but doesn't regard all the seasons and could be at odds due to concerns already explained in the notes I mentioned earlier. Check them out if you feel the need</sub>

Comment: @asgard, regarding [your edit](https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/62034) i dont have time to verify myself, but I do want to give you a chance even though you're a new account. I've improved things on random forums a good few times with a new account a few times too. If you can post an imgur album or something with the title cards for those eps showing the in-universe dates I can accept. Otherwise I cant just blindly say "from Viteracf but legit improvements by asgard"

Answer (score 0):

I want to fix the answers from the person above me a little

1. **Hidamari sketch x Hoshi Sp1B** Year 0 7th Apr (**the first chronological eps**)
2. **Hidamari sketch x Hoshi 2B** Year 1 19th Jul (**after Hidasketch eps 6**)
3. **Hidamari sketch x Hoshi Sp2A** Year 2 23rd Jun (**after x Hoshi Sp1A**)
4. **Hidamari sketch x Hoshi Sp2B** Year 2 30th Jul (**after x Hoshi eps 12**)